# What is use of Virtual table auto generated tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, view, virtual-table

I was doing some debugging with sql queries, executed following to create an Virtual Table:

```
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE email_fts USING fts3(subject, body, "to", "from");
```

& checked schema where it showing additional 3 table references to created Virtual table.

```
sqlite> .schema

CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE email_fts USING fts3(subject, body, "to", "from");

CREATE TABLE 'email_fts_content'(docid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'c0subject', 'c1body', 'c2to', 'c3from');

CREATE TABLE 'email_fts_segments'(blockid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, block BLOB);

CREATE TABLE 'email_fts_segdir'(level INTEGER,idx INTEGER,start_block INTEGER,leaves_end_block INTEGER,end_block INTEGER,root BLOB,PRIMARY KEY(level, idx));
```

Anyone please explain:

- what is use of fits_content/segments/segdir,
- who use these.
- Purpose of use surely be related to searching but how these related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#shadow_tables):

> For each FTS virtual table in a database, three to five real (non-virtual) tables are created to store the underlying data. These real tables are called "shadow tables".
>   […]